# JSON File to Byte[], need to go Byte[] to JSON string

Tags: c#, json, file-io, arrays

I have JSON in a text file, and I read the bytes of the file into an array:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
```

Now, I want to get a string that contains the JSON data that was in the original file, but I only have the data byte array available.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) instead?

Anyway, you can convert a Byte[] to a String using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)`

Comment: Is there any way to directly converting bytes[] to JSON String instead of converting to string and then JSON String?

Answer (score 4):

You need to setup an encoding and then convert the bytes to a string, like so:

```
System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
string myString = enc.GetString(myByteArray );
```

Although, if your goal is simply to read the JSON into a string, then everyone else's answer is right. Just use File.ReadAllText

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) instead?  That'll give you a string off the bat.

Comment: Because the data[] stream is the only thing available to me at the point where I need to restore the JSON string

Comment: Fair enough, in that case, Simon or Icemanind's suggestion for conversion will do the job :)